# Prestashop filter in dropdown list doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, prestashop

I have problem with filter in Prestashop. Originally in blocklayered.js exist that code:

```js
    $(document).on('click', '#layered_form select',function(e) {
      reloadContent(true);
    });
```

However this code is wrong, because when I click on select - function reloadContent() is started. I want to start that function when user click on option in dropdown list. I changed the code:

```
$(document).on('click', '#layered_form select option', function(e) {
    reloadContent(true);
});
```

Now, my filter work correctly in firefox but doesn't work in chrome. 
What is the reason?

Comment: Chrome (AFAIK Safari too) doesn't support any event to be bound on `option` element. Maybe just use instead `change` event

Comment: I tried but it also doesn't work. i have not idea why. You can take a look at this dropdown list here: http://adf.ly/1Grvzf

Comment: Which dropdown list? Why not providing minimalistic sample which replicates issue?

Comment: https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/336x453q90/537/xoPFEZ.png

Comment: This dropdown list. Minimalistic sample may be not sufficient. Jquery function change, generally work correctly but not in this context. I dont; know reason.

Answer (score 0):

You should instead just use the `change` event of `select` element:

```
$(document).on('change', '#layered_form select',function(e) {
    reloadContent(true);
});
```